# Prove that if $|f(z)|<1+|z|^2$ $f$ is degree at most 2

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $|f(z)|<1+|z|^2$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2/

I have no idea where to go on this one. I was thinking max mod theorem.

Comment: Can you precise if $f$ polynomial is a requirement or part of the conclusion ?

Comment: If $f$ analytic everywhere?

Comment: This is carelessly stated. What are the hypotheses on $f?$

Comment: The standard approach for an entire function would be to apply  Cauchy’s inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a special case of the "Extended" Liouville's Theorem.

> If $|f(z)| \le C |z|^N$ for large $|z|$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$.

Proof hints:

- $f$ is analytic everywhere so consider it's power series.
- Use Taylor's theorem to get an expression for $a_k$, $k \ge N.$
- Use Cauchy's integral formula to bound $a_k$.
- Show that the bound goes to $0$ as your radius for the integral goes to infinity.
- Cash money.

Comment: could you flush out the details please?

Comment: flush out which step ?

Comment: I looked up the proof of the extened theorem and I don't see how to modify it for this problem.

Comment: OK here is most of it: Take the analytic expansion around $0$. Then $a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}.$ By the integral formula, $a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} \ dx$ where $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $r$. Now use the triangle inequality and take the limit as $r \rightarrow \infty$. This will show that 'most' of the $a_k$ values are actually $0$! This will allow you to prove what you want.